# c++ pointer allocating more space than specified when using Visual Studio

Tags: c++

When when I run this code in Visual Studio I get a bunch of garbage characters at the end but when I run it in an online compiler I get the exact characters I want?("olleH"). Please be gentle, im a noob.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {
    std::string stringOne{ "Hello" };
    int stringLength = stringOne.length();
    char* stringTwo = new char[stringLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
        *(stringTwo + i) = stringOne[stringLength - i - 1];
    }

    std::string stringThree = stringTwo;
    std::cout << stringThree << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thou shalt terminate all c-style strings will a nul character. No exceptions. You did not do this, so the program doesn't know when to stop reading. It reads off the end of the intended string and into the land of garbage beyond the string. Technically there is no land of garbage and the program invoked [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but garbageland is a common manifestation of undefined behaviour when running off the end of a string.

Comment: Oof I knew I was forgetting something basic. Thanks a lot! user4581301

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you get with the `char* stringTwo = new char[stringLength];` statement when `stringLength` is five (as it is here):

```
 _____stringTwo_____
/                   \
+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+
| ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | <arbitrary data> |
+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+
```

Then, your loop will populate it as follows:

```
 _____stringTwo_____
/                   \
+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+
| o | l | l | e | H | <arbitrary data> |
+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+
```

*Then* you treat is as a C-style string, despite the fact that there is no null terminator on the string. That means string functions will read *beyond* the end of the data and process whatever exists there. What you should be doing is constructing a real C style string, terminator and all:

```
char *stringTwo = new char[stringLength+1];
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i)
    *(stringTwo + i) = stringOne[stringLength - i - 1]; // or: stringTwo[i]
*(stringTwo + stringLength) = '\0';                     //     stringTwo[stringLength]
```

That will give you the more correct:

```
 _______stringTwo________
/                        \
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----------------+
| o | l | l | e | H | \0 |<arbitrary data> |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----------------+
```

---

Of course, the use of C style strings in C++ is pretty much the textbook definition of a bad idea, suitable only in very rare circumstances if any.

Unless you want to be known as a C+ developer (that strange breed of C developer that never *quite* made the transition to C++ fully), you should embrace the more modern stuff found within C++, *including* `std::string` and the stuff from `<algorithms>` (if your need is to get something done rather than learn lower-level programming in an educational context):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string str("Hello");
    std::reverse<std::string::iterator>(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Exission [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) are other C++-isms worth embracing, should they be permitted.

Answer (score -1):

```
std:string is not null terminated string.
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {
    std::string stringOne{ "Hello" };
    int stringLength = stringOne.length();
    char* stringTwo = new char[stringLength+1]; // allocate one byte extra to store null character
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
        *(stringTwo + i) = stringOne[stringLength - i - 1];
    }
    *(stringTwo + stringLength) = '\0'; // add null character
    std::string stringThree = stringTwo;
    std::cout << stringThree << std::endl;
}
```